# Pass data back to UIPickerView

Tags: swift, timer, uipickerview

I'm creating timer app and I want user be able to edit existing timers. For, example, when User click on specific timer, he can edit hours, minutes and seconds, which I get initially from UIPickerView.

I'm using this code to get hours, minutes and seconds for new timers:

```
    var hour: Int = 0
    var minutes: Int = 0
    var seconds: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""

    var totalSeconds: Int {
        return hour * 3600 + minutes  * 60 + seconds
    }

}
     extension TimerSelectViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

         func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
             return 3
         }

         func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
             switch component {
             case 0:
                 return 25
             case 1, 2:
                 return 60
             default:
                 return 0
             }
         }

         func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return pickerView.frame.size.width/4
         }

         func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
             switch component {
             case 0:
                 return "\(row) hr"
             case 1:
                 return "\(row) min"
             case 2:
                 return "\(row) sec"
             default:
                 return ""
             }
         }
         func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
             switch component {
             case 0:
                 hour = row
             case 1:
                 minutes = row
             case 2:
                 seconds = row
             default:
                 break;
             }
         }
```

But how I can pass data back to UIPickerView when user want to edit a timer and not creates a new timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPickerView has a method for preselecting rows: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614382-selectrow

E.g.:

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
// 14:00:00 or 2:00:00 PM, add more select commands as needed
picker.selectRow(14, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```